# webbrowser with emoji / emoticon

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, webbrowser-control

Folks,

I'm doing a post on a web page with emoji / emoticon. But after posted the site does not display the emoticon. Must you use a different Encoding? If so how can I do?
Example have this emoji ⛪ the site only shows me that ⛪ Other special characters appear.

```
if (currentElement.GetAttribute("type") == "submit")
    if (currentElement.Name == "view_post") 
    {
       string postagem = txtPublicacao.Text;

        HtmlElement elea = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0");
        if (elea != null)
            elea.SetAttribute("value", postagem);

        currentElement.InvokeMember("click");

    }
```

Comment: How are you doing the post? Show us the code[s].

Comment: Sorry, edit the post.
Follows the code

Comment: Look posted 4 emoticons only appears 1:
⛪

Answer (score 0):

I think you can prevent yourself from experiencing some future grief by ensuring that blocks are enclosed in brackets like so:

```
if (currentElement.GetAttribute("type") == "submit")
{
    if (currentElement.Name == "view_post") 
    {
       string postagem = txtPublicacao.Text;

        HtmlElement elea = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0");
        // if condition and response either on one line:
        if (elea != null) elea.SetAttribute("value", postagem);
        // ...or use "{}" in preparation for possible future additions to the reponse to the if condition
        if (elea != null) 
        {
            elea.SetAttribute("value", postagem);
        }
        currentElement.InvokeMember("click");    
    }
}
```

Or better yet, since you have two consecutive "ifs" before code is executed, combine them like so:

```
if ((currentElement.GetAttribute("type") == "submit") && 
    (currentElement.Name == "view_post"))
{
    string postagem = txtPublicacao.Text;    
    HtmlElement elea = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0");
    if (elea != null) elea.SetAttribute("value", postagem);
    currentElement.InvokeMember("click");    
}
```

Comment: Cool, did this change, thank you!
Now on posting emoticons know any way?